# Can we mark a change in Google Drive's Realtime API as un-undoable?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

We need to migrate some data in our users documents, which we are accessing through Google Drive's Realtime API. We don't want them to undo the change, since that would take the document back to a format that our application no longer understands. I know we could refresh the page, and that would clear the undo stack, but is there a more targeted way of preventing them from undoing that change?

Comment: We've also been looking for the ability to do this. We use the JS version of the Realtime API and the best we've come up with so far is a page reload or reconnect to the document after we do the migration. Not the best experience, but preventing an undo of a the migration is pretty important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  Its been a frequent feature request though, so we are looking at adding support for it.